# Show Ellipsis(...) Button When Text Exceeds Range WPF

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I have one TextBlock having width say 100. When the text length is a large one I want to show the characters that is accomodated in that textblock and a (...) button besides the text to specify user that more text is also there. Upon click on that (...) button, the full text will be shown in a separate pop up window.

So i want how the dynamic (...) button will be shown whenever the text length exceed the size of the textblock. Please answer

Answer (score 11):

This isn't exactly what you want, but it's a similar idea and just uses the baked-in stuff:

```
<TextBlock MaxWidth="200"
           Text="{Binding YourLongText}"
           TextTrimming="WordEllipsis"
           ToolTip="{Binding YourLongText}" />
```

So you have a TextBlock with a maximum width, and when the text can't fit it displays an ellipsis ("..."). Hovering over the TextBlock with your mouse will show the full text in a ToolTip.

Comment: Thanks Matt for your response. But I want to show a button automatically when the textlength exceeds. In TextTrimming ... appears, but I want a button having content ... should appear.

Answer (score 3):

Just experience the same requirement for adding ellipsis on button so adding the solution here

```
<Style x:Key="editButton" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent" />                          
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                        <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                            <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center" >
                                <ContentPresenter.Resources>
                                    <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
                                        <Setter Property="TextTrimming" Value="CharacterEllipsis"></Setter>
                                    </Style>
                                </ContentPresenter.Resources>
                            </ContentPresenter>
                        </Border>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>                      
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
```

Notice the resources in content presenter.

Comment: For others like me: use ContentPresenter not ContentControl.

Answer (score 1):

I believe what you want is to set the [TextTrimming property.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.textblock.texttrimming.aspx)  Settng it to WordElilipsis or CharacterEllipsis should provide what you need.

Answer (score 1):

My solution to the problem is probably overkill, but allows for some configuration and control.
I created a behavior that allows me to set the character limit for each binding.

```
 internal class EllipsisStringBehavior
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty CharacterLimitDependencyProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("CharacterLimit", typeof(int), typeof(EllipsisStringBehavior), new PropertyMetadata(255, null, OnCoerceCharacterLimit));
    public static readonly DependencyProperty InputTextDependencyProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("InputText", typeof(string), typeof(EllipsisStringBehavior), new PropertyMetadata(string.Empty, OnInputTextChanged));

    // Input Text
    public static string GetInputText(DependencyObject dependencyObject)
    {
        return Convert.ToString(dependencyObject.GetValue(InputTextDependencyProperty));
    }
    public static void SetInputText(DependencyObject dependencyObject, string inputText)
    {
        dependencyObject.SetValue(InputTextDependencyProperty, inputText);
    }

    // Character Limit
    public static int GetCharacterLimit(DependencyObject dependencyObject)
    {
        return Convert.ToInt32(dependencyObject.GetValue(CharacterLimitDependencyProperty));
    }
    public static void SetCharacterLimit(DependencyObject dependencyObject, object characterLimit)
    {
        dependencyObject.SetValue(CharacterLimitDependencyProperty, characterLimit);
    }

    private static void OnInputTextChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        TextBlock textblock = (TextBlock)d;

        string input = e.NewValue == null ? string.Empty : e.NewValue.ToString();
        int limit = GetCharacterLimit(d);

        string result = input;

        if (input.Length > limit && input.Length != 0)
        {
            result = $"{input.Substring(0, limit)}...";
        }

        textblock.Text = result;
    }

    private static object OnCoerceCharacterLimit(DependencyObject d, object baseValue)
    {
        return baseValue;
    }
}
```

I then simply add the using to my user control...

```
<UserControl 
 xmlns:behavior="clr-namespace:My_APP.Helper.Behavior"
 d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
```

...and apply the behavior to the TextBlock control I wish to use it on.

```
<TextBlock Margin="0,8,0,8"
 behavior:EllipsisStringBehavior.CharacterLimit="10" 
 behavior:EllipsisStringBehavior.InputText="{Binding Path=DataContext.FeedItemTwo.Body, Mode=OneWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
 Style="{StaticResource MaterialDesignSubheadingTextBlock}"  
 FontSize="14"/>
```

Hope this helps.